# Civ V - Longbowman doesn't have range 3 or strength 18

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing Civ V installed from Steam on my ubuntu 14.04 OS.

As I've found everywhere on the internet ([wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Longbowman_(Civ5))), the longbowman in Civ V should have a range of 3, but in my game it has a regular range of 2. See the snapshots.

Does anyone know if there is a reason why my longbowman would have a range of 2 instead of 3? Is there a tech that I need? Or does the unit need to be promoted?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The range of 2 is correct. Longbowman have a base of 2 range but they also start with the promotion which gives +1 range. The result is mostly the same- they should be able to shoot 3 tiles away.

If they had 3 range base, they would be able to take the range promotion on top of that for 4 range- which would be a bit silly. On the plus side, it means they upgrade into Gatling Guns with extra range (if you have Gods & Kings).

The 15 strength is also correct in Vanilla. The Gods & Kings expansion changes the combat system and, for balance, a lot of the unit strength values. Annoyingly, the wiki doesn't mention this. Crossbowmen and their unique versions only have 15 strength in vanilla.

Comment: Oh I see, so indeed the unit needs to be promoted. Does that mean other range unit does not have this particular promotion available?

Comment: @GuillaumeBois Crossbowmen and other range units can take the Range promotion with enough experience but it's fairly deep in the promotion tree.

Comment: @GuillaumeBois I found out the reason your longbow had such low strength too- it's edited into my answer.

Comment: Confirmed, I was able to attack at range 3. When I tried I was probably behind a hill. I will edit the question title to remove the word bug.